# Unable to generate code coverage for integration test module using jacoco

Tags: java, maven, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin, test-coverage

I have a maven project with the attached directory structure.

[image]

It contains a parent.pom and two modules.

1. plugin
   1.1 It contains the actual source code inside src/main
   1.2 It contains the unit test cases inside src/test
2. integration-tests
   2.1 It contains all the integration tests for the plugin/src/main source code.

Now I am trying to add Jacoco Plugin to generate code coverage results that include all the unit and integration testcases.

My reports for the **plugin** module is getting generated but the one for the **integration-tests** is blank.

I am attaching all the POM.xml below.

Parent POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.pom</groupId>
        <artifactId>public-pom</artifactId>
        <version>6.3.1</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.atlassian.confluence.plugins.xmlrpc.bloggingrpc</groupId>
    <artifactId>bloggingrpc-parent</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.5-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <name>Confluence Blogging RPC Plugin Parent</name>
    <description>
        <![CDATA[Blogging API Plugin. This plugin contains an implementation of the Blogger 1.0 API and the MetaWeblog
        API that allows any clients that implement these APIs to post news items to confluence.]]>
    </description>
    <url>https://studio.plugins.atlassian.com/wiki/display/BLOG</url>

    <modules>
      <module>plugin</module>
      <module>integration-tests</module>
    </modules>

    <scm>
        <connection>scm:git:git@bitbucket.org:atlassian/confluence-blogging-rpc-plugin.git</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:git:git@bitbucket.org:atlassian/confluence-blogging-rpc-plugin.git</developerConnection>
        <url>https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/confluence-blogging-rpc-plugin</url>
        <tag>HEAD</tag>
    </scm>

    <properties>
        <atlassian.plugin.key>com.atlassian.confluence.plugins.xmlrpc.bloggingrpc</atlassian.plugin.key>
        <confluence.version>8.6.0-rc1</confluence.version>
        <confluence.data.version>${confluence.version}</confluence.data.version>
        <atlassian.product.test-lib.version>3.0.0</atlassian.product.test-lib.version>
        
        <amps8.version>8.11.4</amps8.version>
        <jvm.args.custom /> <!-- Allows to specify custom arguments in build scripts -->
        <jvm.args.xmx>1024m</jvm.args.xmx>
        <jvm.args>-Xmx${jvm.args.xmx} ${jvm.args.custom}</jvm.args>
        
        <hamcrest.version>2.2</hamcrest.version>
        <containerId>tomcat9x</containerId>
        <server>localhost</server>

        <!-- For the flaky test reporter profile. -->
        <!-- override the versions of the listed plugins in amps -->
        <version.override.set>maven-failsafe-plugin</version.override.set>
        <!-- failsafe 2.20.1 or newer required for rerun support. Double check the version from the parent-pom -->
        <surefire.version>2.22.2</surefire.version>
        <download.maven.plugin.version>1.6.8</download.maven.plugin.version>
        <webdriver.browser>firefox</webdriver.browser>
        <failOnMilestoneOrReleaseCandidateDeps>false</failOnMilestoneOrReleaseCandidateDeps>
        <sonar-maven-plugin.version>3.11.0.3922</sonar-maven-plugin.version>
        <!-- SonarQube properties (these are inherited for each module) -->
        <sonar.links.issue>https://jira.atlassian.com/projects/CONFSRVDEV/issues</sonar.links.issue>
        <sonar.links.ci>https://server-syd-bamboo.internal.atlassian.com/allPlans.action</sonar.links.ci>
        <sonar.projectName>Confluence Blogging Rpc Plugin</sonar.projectName>
        <sonar.projectKey>confluence-blogging-rpc-plugin</sonar.projectKey>
        <!-- For multiple modules -->
        <sonar.moduleKey>${project.artifactId}</sonar.moduleKey>
    </properties>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>flaky</id>
            <properties>
                <ci.tests.skipAfterFailureCount>10</ci.tests.skipAfterFailureCount>
                <ci.tests.rerunFailingTestsCount>2</ci.tests.rerunFailingTestsCount>
            </properties>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.googlecode.maven-download-plugin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>download-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${download.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>download-flaky-configuration</id>
                                <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>wget</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <url>https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/confluence-server/bamboo/issuecreator_plugins_config.json</url>
                                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.testOutputDirectory}</outputDirectory>
                                    <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <skipAfterFailureCount>${ci.tests.skipAfterFailureCount}</skipAfterFailureCount>
                            <rerunFailingTestsCount>${ci.tests.rerunFailingTestsCount}</rerunFailingTestsCount>
                            <properties>
                                <property>
                                    <name>listener</name>
                                    <value>com.atlassian.test.reporting.JUnitFlakyTestListener</value>
                                </property>
                            </properties>
                            <systemPropertyVariables>
                                <junitflakylistener.runnerId>${env.bamboo_buildResultKey}</junitflakylistener.runnerId>
                                <junitflakylistener.branchName>${env.bamboo_planRepository_1_branchName}</junitflakylistener.branchName>
                                <!-- issue creation kill switch; by default, issues will be created on branch builds as well -->
                                <junitflakylistener.trackFlakyTest>true</junitflakylistener.trackFlakyTest>
                                <junitflakylistener.flakyTestFilePath>target/failsafe-reports/flakey-tests.txt</junitflakylistener.flakyTestFilePath>
                                <junitflakylistener.jiraProjectConfigPath>issuecreator_plugins_config.json</junitflakylistener.jiraProjectConfigPath>
                                <junitflakylistener.jiraUserName>${env.bamboo_issuecreator_jiraUserName}</junitflakylistener.jiraUserName>
                                <junitflakylistener.jiraPassword>${env.bamboo_issuecreator_jiraPassword}</junitflakylistener.jiraPassword>
                            </systemPropertyVariables>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.atlassian</groupId>
                    <artifactId>flaky-test-reporter</artifactId>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.googlecode.maven-download-plugin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>download-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${download.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.atlassian.drs</groupId>
                <artifactId>dependency-report-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.17</version>
                <configuration>
                    <project>confluence-blogging-rpc-plugin</project>
                    <gracefulFailure>true</gracefulFailure>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>upload</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${sonar-maven-plugin.version}</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Integration-test POM.xml

**NOTE** Since the source code is present inside plugins/ I have explicitly included the path in jacoco agent definition.

*${project.basedir}/../plugin/**/**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.confluence.plugins.xmlrpc.bloggingrpc</groupId>
        <artifactId>bloggingrpc-parent</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.5-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>bloggingrpc-integration-tests</artifactId>

    <name>Confluence Blogging RPC Plugin Integration Tests</name>

    <properties>
        <sonar.tests>src/test</sonar.tests>
    </properties>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.atlassian.confluence</groupId>
                <artifactId>confluence-plugins-platform-test-pom</artifactId>
                <version>${confluence.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.atlassian.confluence.plugin</groupId>
                <artifactId>func-test-package</artifactId>
                <version>${atlassian.product.test-lib.version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.atlassian.confluence.plugin</groupId>
                <artifactId>func-test</artifactId>
                <version>${atlassian.product.test-lib.version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
                <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
                <version>5.1.0</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.confluence</groupId>
            <artifactId>confluence-stateless-test-runner</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>atlassian-webdriver-core</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest</artifactId>
            <version>${hamcrest.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
            <version>${hamcrest.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hamcrest.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.10</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>${project.basedir}/../plugin/**/*</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>it-prepare-agent</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent-integration</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>it-report</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report-integration</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.atlassian.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>confluence-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${amps8.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>webdriver-tests</id>
                        <phase>integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <extractDependencies>false</extractDependencies>
                    <containerId>${containerId}</containerId>
                    <jvmArgs>${jvm.args}</jvmArgs>
                    <productVersion>${confluence.version}</productVersion>
                    <productDataVersion>${confluence.data.version}</productDataVersion>
                    <server>${server}</server>
                    <output>${project.build.directory}/output.log</output>
                    <pluginArtifacts>
                        <pluginArtifact>
                            <groupId>com.atlassian.confluence.plugins.xmlrpc.bloggingrpc</groupId>
                            <artifactId>bloggingrpc</artifactId>
                            <version>${project.version}</version>
                        </pluginArtifact>
                    </pluginArtifacts>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <confluence.version>${confluence.version}</confluence.version> <!-- system property required by Functest RPC plugin -->
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Plugins POM.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.confluence.plugins.xmlrpc.bloggingrpc</groupId>
        <artifactId>bloggingrpc-parent</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.5-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>bloggingrpc</artifactId>
    <packaging>atlassian-plugin</packaging>

    <name>Confluence Blogging RPC Plugin</name>

    <properties>
        <sonar.tests>src/test</sonar.tests>
        <sonar.sources>src/main</sonar.sources>
    </properties>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.atlassian.confluence</groupId>
                <artifactId>confluence-plugins-platform-pom</artifactId>
                <version>${confluence.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.confluence</groupId>
            <artifactId>confluence</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>net.sourceforge.cssparser</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cssparser</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>net.sourceforge.nekohtml</groupId>
                    <artifactId>nekohtml</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest</artifactId>
            <version>${hamcrest.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
            <version>${hamcrest.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hamcrest.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.10</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>ut-prepare-agent</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>ut-report</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.atlassian.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>confluence-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${amps8.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <extractDependencies>false</extractDependencies>
                    <containerId>${containerId}</containerId>
                    <jvmArgs>${jvm.args}</jvmArgs>
                    <productVersion>${confluence.version}</productVersion>
                    <productDataVersion>${confluence.data.version}</productDataVersion>
                    <server>${server}</server>
                    <output>${project.build.directory}/output.log</output>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <webdriver.browser>${webdriver.browser}</webdriver.browser>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

when do I maven clean verify all unit tests and integration tests are getting executed.

The jacoco agent for plugins directory is getting the data from the classes

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jacoco:0.8.10:report (ut-report) @ bloggingrpc ---
[INFO] Loading execution data file /Users/psaraiwala/Desktop/Packages/code_coverage/confluence/confluence-blogging-rpc-plugin/plugin/target/jacoco.exec
[INFO] Analyzed bundle 'Confluence Blogging RPC Plugin' with 4 classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --< com.atlassian.confluence.plugins.xmlrpc.bloggingrpc:bloggingrpc-integration-tests >--
[INFO] Building Confluence Blogging RPC Plugin Integration Tests 4.3.5-SNAPSHOT [3/3]
[INFO]   from integration-tests/pom.xml
```

but the same for integration-tests is not working.

```
[INFO] --- jacoco:0.8.10:report-integration (it-report) @ bloggingrpc-integration-tests ---
[INFO] Loading execution data file /Users/psaraiwala/Desktop/Packages/code_coverage/confluence/confluence-blogging-rpc-plugin/integration-tests/target/jacoco-it.exec
[INFO] Analyzed bundle 'Confluence Blogging RPC Plugin Integration Tests' with 0 classes
```

**NOTE** This bundle does not contain any source code hence I included the source code of the plugin class in the agent definition .Still it is not working??

Tried chat-gpt as well.
Couldn't find a working solution.

Kindly help!!!!

Comment: Why not following naming convention `*Test.java` unit test (maven-surefire-plugin) and integration tests `*IT.java` (maven-failsafe-plugin)... using most recent version (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/) ... etc.

Comment: @khmarbaise -  I am not the creater of the repo and I can't make changes to the structure or Names. I have been asked to just implement code coverage.

Comment: That will not work and makes it more compilated than needed... Maven is based on the convention over configuration pardigm...

Comment: @khmarbaise I know but my hands are tied here. I need to generate coverage reports based on the current structure. Is there a way I can connect with you to show you exactly what is happening and if you can help me in some way?